# Access criteria to return data with date greater than previous Friday

Tags: ms-access-2007

I currently pull a date field into a query I'm using for access 2207 with the criteria of:

`create_dt_tm >Now()-7` (which pulls everything created in the last 7 days)

Is it possible to make the criteria greater than the previous Friday? hence only pulling `>Now()-3` if my query is run on `Monday`, `-4` on a `Tuesday` etc?

Answer (score 1):

The [Weekday()](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Weekday-Function-05d360d7-2c3f-4691-9448-c96ea0351940) function returns

```
Sunday     1
Monday     2
Tuesday    3
Wednesday  4
Thursday   5
Friday     6
Saturday   7
```

and the offsets to the previous Friday are

```
Sunday     -2
Monday     -3
Tuesday    -4
Wednesday  -5
Thursday   -6
Friday     -7
Saturday   -1
```

so the expression

```
DateAdd("d", -1 - IIf(Weekday(Date) = 7, 0, Weekday(Date)), Date)
```

will return the date of the previous Friday.